# Power BI, collapsible text

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way to include a collapsible text in a Power BI report?
The purpose would be to add text into the report (essentially explanations for the user on the data and the methodology), but without the text being allways present and taking real state. Right now I elaborate separate documentation on the reports but it could be more effective to be able to have the text appear right when the user needs documentation in the report.

Comment: If your documentation is large, you could also split it into pages/chapters, store it in a table ("Chapter Name", "Description"), and have a slicer by "Chapter Name" next to the visual displaying the "Description".

Answer (score 2):

I would add the text as either a Multi-Row Card, Table or Long Text Viewer (Custom Visual).

Then I would reduce the frame size of that object to show just the first line of text.  Users can click the Focus Mode button to expand the visual to a full screen view.

That text might event say "Click the Focus Mode button (top right) to expand ...".

Comment: This is the best alternative at this time. We can keep an eye on other potential alternatives as Power BI evolves.

Comment: I'm sorry but I noticed Text Box doesn't provide a focus mode and if I tried to use Table or Long Text Viewer I would have to enter my text in a table first as a data item which would not allow for text formatting, e.g. new lines, bold titles, etc.

Comment: That's for pointing that out - I've edited my answer to remove the Text Box option.  Text formatting in PBI is indeed very lightweight, but that is beyond the scope of this forum to solve ... I suggest you find relevant entries on UserVoice and vote them up.